# Register a decorator using non-named container registrations?

Tags: decorator, autofac

Is there a way in Autofac to register a decorator for an interface without forcing the original registration to be named? I want to generically register a decorator for ALL registered implementations, unfortunately, I cannot define a name for all of them (some are registered in a library I cannot adjust).

Comment: Have you considered use the adapter as a (instead of) decorator?